# Angular controller scope item as child of a scope function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to angular & js in general, and followed a great tutorial by [Dan Wahlin](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/using-an-angularjs-factory-to-interact-with-a-restful-service) that shows how to connect your angular client to a REST interface.

I'm calling the REST interface to grab a bunch of data, then using the client to do useful things with that data, calculations etc.

What I can't figure out is how to cleanly manipulate data from the REST factory inside my controller.

Inside my MainController.js I can grab the order data and declare it as a scope item:

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'dataFactory', function($scope, dataFactory) {
    $scope.orders;
    getOrders();

    function getOrders() {
        dataFactory.getOrders()
            .success(function (ord) {
                $scope.orders = ord;
            })
            .error(function (error) {
                $scope.status = 'Unable to load order data: ' + error.message;
            });
    }
}
```

Now I want to do things inside the controller using the data in the returned $scope.orders array. When I try to find the length like this, it works:

```
function getOrders() {
        dataFactory.getOrders()
            .success(function (ord) {
                $scope.orders = ord;
                // This is me using the $scope.orders data to declare another controller item
                $scope.ordersCount = $scope.orders.length;
                })
                .error(function (error) {
                    $scope.status = 'Unable to load order data: ' + error.message;
                });
        }
```

However, I need to add a ton of different items using data from the $scope.orders variable in different ways. I can do it all inside the function like the $scope.ordersCount item above, but the code seems messy and if I add different types of calculations in here, the function gets longer and doesn't seem right. However when I try to access the $scope.orders array outside of the function it doesn't work. Here's what I tried:

```
$scope.orders = getOrders();

    function getOrders() {
        dataFactory.getOrders()
            .success(function (ord) {
                $scope.orders = ord;
                // I also tried 'return ord' here too
            })
            .error(function (error) {
                $scope.status = 'Unable to load order data: ' + error.message;
            });
    }

    $scope.ordersCount = $scope.orders.length;
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I declare my array as $scope.orders and then use it outside the function?

Currently the console is just giving me "cannot read property length of undefined" which tells me my $scope.orders is not available outside the function.

Comment: Because javascript won't wait the function.. it is called _asynchronous_... why do you need to know the length? What are you trying with it?

Comment: Hi @WashingtonGuedes - The orders array contains a list of orders with all their details, e.g. 10 items which each have a 'price', 'customer', 'employee' etc. The length just gives me a quick and easy way to get a total number of orders (items in the array). I am however using the same mechanism to for example sum the 'price' item within each array item to get a totalRevenue figure - and a bunch of other calculations.

Comment: You might do it inside the _success_ function... because before it success you do not have nothing to process/sum/... OR create a function that get the `orders` as parameter and that function will do your process... but, anyways you will only call that function in the _success_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be changing the

```
$scope.ordersCount = $scope.orders.length;
```

After its loaded via ajax as shown below.

```
 dataFactory.getOrders()
            .success(function (ord) {
                $scope.orders = ord;
                // I also tried 'return ord' here too
            })
```

So the best way to do in angular 1 is to use $watch inside your controller.

```
$scope.$watch('orders', function() {
        // called when $scope.orders changes.
        $scope.ordersCount = $scope.orders.length;
    }, true);
```

Reference [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/watch-digest-apply.html#watch)

Hope this helps!

Comment: This works well Cyril thanks. It gets my ultimate outcome and loads my data to the controller when it's ready. I'm still getting the error in the console on initial page load, but I'd imagine that will disappear if I assign a default value to my $scope.orders array.

Comment: yeah hope so...with watch you will get notified(or your watch function) whenever there is a change in the `$scope.orders`

Answer (score 2):

In your above code sample what happening is that your rest services takes some time to get the data and bind with $scope.orders, before that your code line $scope.ordersCount = $scope.orders.length; gets executed, for that you are getting undefined error in console.

Try this:

```
$scope.orders = getOrders();

function getOrders() {
    dataFactory.getOrders()
        .success(function (ord) {
            $scope.orders = ord;
            // I also tried 'return ord' here too
        })
        .error(function (error) {
            $scope.status = 'Unable to load order data: ' + error.message;
        });
       $scope.ordersCount = $scope.orders.length; // Just putting this line inside rest function
       console.log($scope.ordersCount)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this - nice explanation of what's going on - I must be misplacing your code as it still gives me the error in the console. Where exactly would I place it?

Comment: Replace the given sample with your last example.